# moving through a tree - wizard style (asp.net mvc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Let us say I have a rooted tree which consists of nodes. Each node contains some data. I would like to allow the user to move through the tree whilst a (partial) view shows the current node's data and allows the user to move back and forward (back only if the node is not a root node and forward only if the node is not a terminal node).

Each move posts back the whole tree plus the current node (potentially ajaxified).

I am just wondering if someone has implemented a similar scenario and if so, I would appreciate any pointers. Many thanks.

Comment: a practical example would probably help us to get a better idea of what you are looking for

Comment: It basically is a conditional form. each node/view is either used to collect a number or a choice (from some choices in the node). I envisage to create the tree either from an xml file, database or programmatically). If the user reaches a terminal node the data is posted.

Comment: Please add a sample tree representation (xml file, you said?) which you would send to the client to your question.

Comment: I have no idea yet. I am just trying to figure out the mechanics. One idea would be to GET all the tree data (json, xml) and then do something via javascript and finally POST the path from the root node to the terminal node, which would be the form data. whilst moving along the nodes I collect either numbers or an option. The chosen option and possibly number determines the next node.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure exactly on the requirements, but perhaps this is what you are looking for:

[wizard forms in mvc](http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that's a standard 'serial' wizard step form (with only one path from the root node to the terminal node) and is no problem. I am interested in a non-serial form (see comment above). The disadvantage of this approach is also that the 'form data' is hard coded in the HTML.

Comment: found something related: but not quite what I am looking for: http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/select-chain.php